# allow multiple clients to listen to ThreadedHTTPServer python 3

Tags: python, http, server, client

I need to pass webcam images to localhost in order to view the webcam in a browser. At the same time I need to use the webcam to feed a youtube stream. I have python3 as my language.

When I capture from the webcam `cv2.capture('/dev/video0')` the webcam is locked so I can't reach it for a second time until I release it. I prefer not to release and recapture it 60 times a second.

I use the following code for the http server:

```
server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('localhost', port), CamHandler)
```

here CamHandler is a class with the function `do_GET(self)` getting 60 times per second a still from the webcam and sends the correct headers along.

So in the browser it shows up and in the stream to youtube (via ffmpeg) it works, but not both at the same time.

What can I do about it? If your answer is "use sockets", please elaborate on it.

**UPDATE**

Here is the full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
import sys 
sys.path.append("cv2") 
import cv2 
from PIL import Image 
import threading 
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer 
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn 
from io import BytesIO 
import time 

capture=None



class CamHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        global capture
        if self.path.endswith('stream.mjpeg'):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--jpgboundary')
            self.end_headers()
            camId = "http://localhost:8091/camera.mjpeg"
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            fontsize = .8
            while True:
                try:
                    with open("currentCamera.txt","r") as f:
                        newCamId = f.read().splitlines() 
                    if newCamId != camId:
                        capture.release();
                        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(''.join(newCamId))
                        print ("camera changed from ", camId, " to ", newCamId)
                        camId = newCamId

                    rc,img = capture.read()
                    if not rc:
                        continue

                    with open("subtitle.txt","r") as f:
                        subtitle = f.read().splitlines()
                        subtitle = ''.join(subtitle).strip()
                        if len(subtitle) > 2:
                            textsize = cv2.getTextSize(subtitle, font, fontsize, 2)[0]
                            textX = (img.shape[1] - textsize[0]) // 2
                            textY = img.shape[0] - textsize[1] - 30
                            cv2.rectangle(img,(textX-10,textY-20),(textX+textsize[0]+10,textY+textsize[1]),(255,255,255),-1)
                            cv2.putText(img,subtitle,(textX,textY+8),font,fontsize,(0,0,0),2)

                    imgRGB=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    jpg = Image.fromarray(imgRGB)
                    tmpFile = BytesIO() 
                    jpg.save(tmpFile,'JPEG')
                    self.wfile.write(b"--jpgboundary")
                    self.send_header('Content-type','image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-length',str(tmpFile.getbuffer().nbytes))
                    self.end_headers()
                    jpg.save(self.wfile,'JPEG')
                    time.sleep(1/60)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    break
            return
        if self.path.endswith('camera.mjpeg'):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--jpgboundary')
            self.end_headers()
            camId = "/dev/video0"
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            fontsize = .8
            while True:
                try:
                    rc,img = capture.read()
                    if not rc:
                        continue
                    imgRGB=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    jpg = Image.fromarray(imgRGB)
                    tmpFile = BytesIO() 
                    jpg.save(tmpFile,'JPEG')
                    self.wfile.write(b"--jpgboundary")
                    self.send_header('Content-type','image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-length',str(tmpFile.getbuffer().nbytes))
                    self.end_headers()
                    jpg.save(self.wfile,'JPEG')
                    time.sleep(1/60)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    break
            return


class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""

def main():
    global capture
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/video0")
    capture.set(3,1920)
    capture.set(4,1080)
    global img

    try:
        server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('localhost', 8091), CamHandler)
        print ("server started on port 8091")
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        capture.release()
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can not show both http://localhost:8091/stream.mjpeg and http://localhost:8091/camera.mjpeg in my browser. Moreover, when I try http://localhost:8091/stream.mjpeg as input for ffmpeg the python script crashes.

**UPDATE 2**
De error is:

```
[mpjpeg @ 0xaa4148c0] Expected boundary '--' not found, instead found a line of # bytes
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: What is `ThreadedHTTPServer`? What makes you think that `ThreadedHTTPServer` only allows for one single client connection at a time? Why do you expect the issue to be with the server, instead of the `CamHandler`? You already stated that `cv2.capture` gains exclusive access to the cam; I'd investigate towards that end. Please share the code of your `CamHandler` and `ThreadedHTTPServer` in case it is your own implementation. If not, please let us know which package you took it from. It is hard to understand what is happening from that one line of code you shared.

Comment: @shmee I added the full code and the error message. I hope you can help me out.